# RAID crash on Mac Studio

Tags: crash, apple-silicon, raid

I have a Mobius 5C external 16TB USB-C RAID connected to a Mac Studio Ultra.
Whenever I try to copy anything to it I get an instant crash and then restart.

The RAID is formatted as HFS+ and I think that might be the problem but I'm not sure. I tried to convert the RAID to APFS in Disk Utility but failed.
I'm trying to avoid an erase and APFS partition. (Monterey 12.6.1)

Comment: Does the RAID work when connected to other Macs?

Comment: It works on Intel Macs but not M1 Monterey

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the size of the cluster. You must have clusters at 64k or higher with the disk utility or SoftRaid on an M1 Mac.
I was at 16k.